# How to implement 8-bit 2:1 multiplexers on a PCB?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, pcb-design, multiplexer, ttl

I need to implement a 2:1 multiplexer for 8-bit data. That is: as inputs it should take two 8-bit numbers and a Select line; and as output an 8-bit number.

I could use two [74HC(T)157](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT157.pdf)s (this is a quad 2-input multiplexer), however, because of its pinout (see below), implementing an 8-bit 2:1 multiplexer would cause a mess on the PCB, and I will probably use several multiplexers in this project.

What is the common way to implement more-than-one-bit (2:1) multiplexers on a PCB? Are there readymade ICs for this (I couldn't find them) or is there a way to keep the PCB uncluttered?

Since I will be home-etching the prints I'm unfortunately rather limited to one layer. The final project should be a home-made CPU of discrete components (really).

---

This is the pinout of the chip I mentioned. For example, 1I0 and 1I1 are inputs for 1Y. S is the common selector.

[image]

Comment: Using '157s is the "standard" answer. Many DRAM controllers were built with exactly that technology. The PCB layout can't always be "pretty" -- just deal with it.

Comment: First, presumably you've already looked at assigning channels by geometric convenience rather than number and decided that doesn't solve your problem.  A CPLD could give you a lot of pinout flexiblity, but perhaps would be "cheating" by your goals.  On the novel front, if your delay budget is generous an (E)PROM loaded with a suitable truth table to use address lines as channel and select inputs could be a solution. A more off-the-shelf solution might be to use tri-state buffers on each side, with only one enabled at a time, or even at an extreme, open-collector logic gates and a pullup.

Comment: @ChrisStratton tri-state buffers or open collectors are excellent ideas. I didn't think of them at first because our teacher had explained the disadvantages of using them (some kind of unexpected behaviour if I remember correctly). However, he was talking about design _on the chip_, and this probably won't cause any issues here. A CPLD would indeed work, I also thought already of a microcontroller, but yeah, that's cheating. However, maybe you could turn this into an answer so that I can show my appreciation? :)

Comment: My first reaction was "oh, how hard could it be?" but after a minute of finger tracing I agree that this would be very hard to route.

Comment: Tristate sounds good, and the routing is nice, but you lose on the package size due to pin count. 2 157s require 2 16-pin packages, but 2 8-bit bus drivers will require 2 20-pin packages, in addition to whatever you need to produce 2 select lines rather than 1 (since the enable lines need to be complementary. I'm not sure which would take more real estate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, presumably you've already looked at assigning channels by geometric convenience rather than number and decided that doesn't solve your problem.

A CPLD could give you a lot of pinout flexiblity, but perhaps would be "cheating" by your goals (though there were board-level mainframe CPUs that used early PALs).

On the novel front, if your delay budget is generous an (E)PROM loaded with a suitable truth table to use address lines as channel and select inputs could be a solution. Perhaps you are already using something similar to hold a table for instruction decode or even microcode.

A more off-the-shelf solution might be to use tri-state buffers on each side, with only one enabled at a time, or even at an extreme, open-collector logic gates and a pullup.

Comment: If there's room I second the discreet solution. That should produce a great layout at least.

Answer (score 5):

The [74HC298A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74as298a.pdf) is more expensive (Digikey has it for $5.81, while the 157 is around $0.70) but it was designed for 4-bit data lines (instead of 4 1-bit data lines), so it has a much friendlier layout:

[image: Pinout of the 298A]

You may be able to route the traces for input 2 upwards and squeeze C1 between D1 and D2. With some luck, this might extend to two of these side-by-side.

Comment: I didn't see that chip before, thanks very much. I think I'm still gonna go with Chris's open collector / tri-state buffer idea looking at the costs (I have loads of suitable transistors laying around), but I'll sure keep an eye on this chip for other designs.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the feedback - this was definitely quite far down on the list and I could see why you wouldn't spot it.

Answer (score 1):

How about a pair of 74LS541s? or 74LS245s? May depend on precisely how you are driving them, they're both cheap enough. I believe you're doomed to a set of jumpers either way.

Comment: That would be the 541, I'm not going to need two-way. Thanks very much. I think I'm going to use a design  similar to its internal circuit (it will likely keep the PCB design easier and I have loads of suitable transistors lying around).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best alternative you will find is a sn74LS399.

But to be honest, you should just do two layers.  You are going to have serious issues getting power and ground to all of your chips with a 1 layer.  It isn't that hard with home etching, just be careful with lining everything up.  There are a lot of examples online of how to do this.